# delete small line below/above triangles

Tags: html, css

I am struggling to delete those lines below and above the triangles on this website: http://bm-translations.de

When you scroll especially on mobile you see them on several triangles. Do you know how to adjust the code?
I tried to adjust height and `top:-1px` etc. but nothing helps to delete those lines.

[image]

```
    /* white triangle */
    .dreieckweiss {
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-left: 120px solid transparent;
        border-right: 120px solid transparent;
        border-top: 60px solid white;
        color: white;
        margin: auto auto;
        font-size: 0px;
        line-height: 0px;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
    }

    /* grey triangle */
    .dreieckgrau {
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-left: 120px solid transparent;
        border-right: 120px solid transparent;
        border-top: 60px solid #E8E8E8;
        color: #E8E8E8;
        margin: auto auto;
        font-size: 0px;
        line-height: 0px;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
    }

    .dreiecktransparent {
      position: relative;
      height: 60px;
      width: 100%;
      padding-top: 60px;
      background: white;
      background-clip: content-box;
      overflow: hidden;
      color: white;
    }
    .dreiecktransparent:before,
    .dreiecktransparent:after {
      position: absolute;
      content: '';
      top: 0;
      width: calc(50% );
      height: 60px;
      background: white;
    }
    .dreiecktransparent:before {
      left: 0;
      transform: skew(60deg);
      transform-origin: right bottom;
    }
    .dreiecktransparent:after {
      right: 0;
      transform: skew(-60deg);
      transform-origin: left bottom;
    }
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code to the body of your question.

Comment: [What have you tried?](https://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Not that I condone bad questions, but  look at your INSPECT WINDOW and search for  `min-height`   --  Start there and you'll FIND your answer that you'r expecting to be HANDED to you ..

Comment: sorry guys, I entered too fast. Pls have a look at my edited question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In another forum I've got the answer. I had to add `margin-top:-1px;` to the classes of the triangels `.dreieckweiß` and `.dreiecktransparent`.

Anyway, thank you for having a look on it!